# Azure API Management - Out of call volume quota

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-management, quota

I am using Azure API Management to manage my Web Apps in Azure. I have not configured any kind of quota limit or rate limit explicitly. Even though if APIs are hit more than 20 times a day I get the following error with status code 403.

> Out of call volume quota. Quota will be replenished in 5.03:23:11.

```
rate-limit (0.032 ms)
{
    "message": "RateLimit counter 8816953412537324468 is incremented"
}
quota (0.894 ms)
{
    "message": "Quota was exceeded.",
    "quota": {
        "level": "Subscription",
        "calls": 100,
        "bandwidth": 0,
        "period": "604800"
    }
}
```

Is there any default quota limit set which I need to modify? Best of my knowledge, above error states that the limit is 100 calls in 7 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using "Starter" as product type.

[image: Call limits based on product type]